findAll() method in MongoRepository returns an empty list
MovieService.java
package com.example.movies;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class MovieService
{
    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    public List<Movie> allMovies()
    {
        return movieRepository.findAll();
    }
}


However, when I changed the code in MovieController.java in the same way video instructs me like below:
package com.example.movies;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/movies")
public class MovieController
{
    @Autowired
    private MovieService movieService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> getAllMovies()
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>>(movieService.allMovies(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}


The findAll() method in allMovie() method does not work as I expected, since it gives me an empty list instead of a list of Movie
My data in MongoDB:
enter image description here
There is no connection error with my MongoDB also. Can you help me by clearly explaining the problem and solution. Thank you for your help and support
EDIT
The error comes from wrong collection's name, which must be movie instead of movies. I have change it and successfully work as I expected.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

What's that backslash doing there, in your curl request? That's not a valid character for use in URLs, as the error tells you.

Apologize for my silly, I have fixed it, and it works fine. Thank you.

\ really isn't a valid character in a URL.
If you really want to send it, you should encode it. Having said that, from the looks of things, this was not intentional. Chances are the tutorial uses it to input a multi-line curl call, and didn't intend to use it as a literal.
